# Warning message in SPD 2010 after migration from 2007 to 2010

Tags: 2010, 2007, designer-workflow, migration, sharepoint-designer

I encountered the below warning message first time and after learning from few web articles I understand that this pop-up message appears when the workflow was created in SPD 2007 and the SharePoint site has migrated from 2007 to 2010. How true is this and can any one elaborate more on this for my better understanding. And what if I click on OK button?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means what it says. Your workflow, created in 2007, currently uses ASPX forms as a user interface. Should you ever change the workflow (now that you are running the site in SP 2010), any future version of the workflow will be using an InfoPath-based form instead of the ASPX form.

The dialog is for information only. Nothing will happen when you click OK.

Things will continue to work as they should.

But when you edit the existing workflow, save and publish it, its form will no longer be your custom ASPX form, but a form that can be customized with InfoPath. InfoPath can be used without any knowledge of ASPX or HTML. It is a forms designer with a WYSIWYG interface (well, almost).

Comment: If the custom ASPX form changes to InfoPath, will it have all the fields and validation that were created in ASPX form?

Comment: Probably not. Automatically created forms will contain only the basics. What are you running? Foundation or Enterprise? See this for Foundation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457061%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: I am running SharePoint Enterprise 2010